# Options to Protect Clickonce from URL hijacking

Tags: security, clickonce

What are mechanisms to protect the manifest url created to launch the ClickOnce application (online only).
e.g. http://www.myworld.com/myapp/OnlineClkOns.application?param1=4579087786575
Option i have to generate this URL on the fly and also have a check within the application to ensure not more than one instance of the application is running.

This solution although not very elegant, does cover the security aspects. want to hear if any better alternatives to restrict the (human) url hijacking.
thnx

UPDATE: I do not wish any user to simply copy the url and use it else where. The URL should be accessed only via a authenticated site. 
I am trying to evaluate the clientapplication services in .net 3.5 which allow smart clients to use Forms based authentication, although that does not solve the problem completely.

Comment: i don't understand the question.  are you trying to prevent people from putting a different value in for param1?

Comment: Yea, I'm also not sure what you mean by URL hijacking. I've heard of domain hijacking and typo squatting, but I don't see how they could apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the https protocols with a third party solution builder. You can read more here [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)